# How to get rid of Kotlin DSL warnings

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, buildsrc

I have just started learning `KotlinDSL` recently.
And in `Android` added `buildSrc`. In this folder I have module plugins: `AppModulePlugin`, `CommonModulePlugin`, `FeatureModulePlugin`. All of this compiles and the application installs correctly, everything is fine. but in these files a warning is displayed:

```
Cannot access 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.Lockable' 
which is a supertype of 'com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension'. 
Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

Please tell me how to get rid of these warnings?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ has had this issue for months unfortunately - it reports correct code as invalid. See [KTIJ-3769](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-3769). I believe it's dependent on ticket [KTIJ-19669](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19669).

As a workaround you can either replace the helper methods that the plugins introduce with 'plain' Gradle Kotlin

```kotlin
// androidExtension { }

project.extensions.configure<BaseExtension> { 
  
}
```

Or only create buildSrc plugins in Kotlin (`*.kt` files), not Kotlin Script (`*.kts` files). This requires using the [`java-gradle-plugin`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project) and defining the plugins in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`.